# Include all object properties with JSON.stringify()'s replacer array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, replace

I have this object, which we'll call `JSONchunk`:

```
{
    "stuffIWant": {
        "number": 123,
        "string": "string",
        "boolean": true
    },
    "boringDumbStuff": {
        "number": 456,
        "boolean": false
    }
}
```

I want to get every property of `stuffIWant`. **However, I don't know all the properties that `stuffIWant` will contain at a given time.**

I was hoping to use `JSON.stringify(JSONchunk, ['stuffIWant'])` but I only get part of the output I want. Namely, it returns `{stuffIWant: {}}`. Close, but no ciggie.

**EDIT:** Here's the result I'm looking for.

```
{
    "stuffIWant": {
        "number": 123,
        "string": "string",
        "boolean": true
    },
}
```

**Is there a way to use a replacer array to return an object AND all of its properties without explicitly referencing those properties in the array?** Or will I need to craft something a little more sophisticated?

Comment: please add an example of the wanted result.

Comment: To loop all properties of an object, use something like for(var i in obj.stuffIWant) {}

Comment: Added! I can't overstate that the properties listed there are not fixed, and may have more or less entries with completely different key names at any given time.

Comment: JSON.stringify(JSONchunk.stuffIWant)? Am I missing something?

Comment: I thought that you were looking something more complicated than just stringifying `JSONchunk.stuffIWant`.  The question was artful ... thats funny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
JSON.stringify(JSONchunk.stuffIWant)
```

Comment: Welp, I made that WAY harder than it needed to be. Thanks for this, it's much easier!

Comment: @Rydash Don't feel too bad. I'm sure Brendan Eich said the same thing after creating Javascript